# How to display the user name, which is inserted from a HTML form

Tags: java, javascript, php, html

I wanted to show the user's name when the user logs in but I can't make it work.

Here is my sample, I created a simple password protected webpage(I'm not gonna put the whole code) but I want to display the name on dashboard.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
    $password = $_POST['pswd'];
    if ( $password == "mypassword" ) { //Replace mypassword with your password it login
        $_SESSION['phplogin'] = true;
        header('Location: dashboard.php'); //Replace dashboard.php with what page you want to go to after succesful login
        exit;
    } else {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    alert('Incorrect Password')
    //-->
    </script>
    <?php
    }
    }

?>
<html>
<form method="post" action="">

<b>whats ur Name: <b/><input type="text" name="txtname" size=15>

<b>What is the Password? </b> <input type="password" name="pswd" size="20">

<input type="submit" name="login" value="Submit"></form>
```

dashboard.php

```
<?php session_start(); require 'approve.php'; ?>

<html>
<body>

blah blah.. blah.. some div html contents here

<font color=white> <?php echo "Logged as: " .$_POST['txtname']; ?> 



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Name will be stored in $_POST['txtname'], if that's what you want

Comment: search google first how to create simple login system in php. and put some effort then if you have any specefic problem then ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first file, save the username in SESSION right after `$_SESSION['phplogin'] = true;`

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['txtname'];
```

On `dashboard.php` :

```
<?php echo "Logged as: " . $_SESSION['name']; ?>
```

Should print the name of the logged user!

Answer (score 0):

you are using $_POST['txtname'] at dashboard.php while no data being posted there.
you are just redirecting user to dashoard.php using header.
solution: either post data to dashboard.php OR save do as below:
at form file save $_POST['txtname'] in session like below:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['txtname'] = $_POST['txtname'];
```

and than at dashboard.php :

```
<?php echo "Logged as: " .$_SESSION['txtname']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First set username in session variable:

```
   <?php
        session_start();
        if(isset($_POST['login']))
        {
        $password = $_POST['pswd'];
        if ( $password == "mypassword" ) { //Replace mypassword with your password it login
            $_SESSION['phplogin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['txtname'];// set in session
            header('Location: dashboard.php'); //Replace dashboard.php with what page you want to go to after succesful login
            exit;
        } else {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        alert('Incorrect Password')
        //-->
        </script>
        <?php
        }
        }

    ?>
    <html>
    <form method="post" action="">

    <b>whats ur Name: <b/><input type="text" name="txtname" size=15>

    <b>What is the Password? </b> <input type="password" name="pswd" size="20">

    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Submit"></form>
```

Then  access it:

```
<?php session_start(); require 'approve.php'; ?>

<html>
<body>

blah blah.. blah.. some div html contents here

<font color=white> <?php echo "Logged as: " .$_SESSION['username']; ?> 



</body>
</html>
```